# Editor in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with editor in jquery datatables.
I'd like to use this project -> https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/htmlTable.html

So, I copy all code to my computer and I run this file, this is my code -> http://wklej.org/hash/cf232c385cc/

But, I get information from console: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor
And I don't know what is a reason this error.

Can You help me? :-)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your reply. I don't know, what I can give yet. All code I copy from datatables website, all links in my file to CSS and JS scipts working :-) When I run this file, I get type error from console: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor . Nothing more

Comment: Do you have a license for the Editor extension? It is not free, so if you don't have a license you'll need to get the trial version, but note that it will expire after 30 (I think) days, at which point you'll have to pay to keep using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datatables, editor library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361234/jquery-datatables-editor-library), which it looks like you made less than 24 hours ago. Don't remake the same question if it doesn't get an answer fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error normally indicates, that the function you are calling is not loaded correctly.

1) Are you loading the javascript containing the `$.fn.dataTable.Editor` function? Can you make sure it is loaded by checking your browsers developer tools?

2) Is your call to `$.fn.dataTable.Editor` wrapped by this line: `$(document).ready(function() {...}`? If not your code executes before the javascript for `$.fn.dataTable.Editor` is loaded and defined and will fail with said error.

If that doesn't help, can you please edit your question to include the code?